# Not receiving email in heroku production environment despite success notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, actionmailer, sendgrid

When I run 'rails s' in my localhost and send an email I receive a notice that "Your name was emailed" and see in the terminal that it seems to have worked. All good!

BUT When I deploy this to heroku and send the email, I get a notice that "Your name was emailed" but never receive the email to my real inbox. Any ideas why I am not receiving the email?

I have set up email for the user authentication system and tested this live on heroku and received email to my real inbox through this same app when I sign up a user - so I believe the config settings are correct.

This is driving me bonkers! appreciate any help :D

Terminal:

```
Started PUT "/profiles/1/email" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-06 14:45:51 +1100
Processing by ProfilesController#email as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"j7RcI5ec+Uckt5mt6Z0m5iD/KvnoWn/GXNzmHMxOjgg=", "name"=>"Scott", "destination"=>"sdasd@gmail.com", "commit"=>"Send Email", "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Profile Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles"  WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered user_mailer/profile.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered user_mailer/profile.text.erb (0.1ms)

UserMailer#profile: processed outbound mail in 9.3ms

Sent mail to destination (5.5ms)
Date: Mon, 06 Oct 2014 14:45:51 +1100
From: noreply@example.com
To: destination
Message-ID: <5432106f1d6ef_12a33fec3247b7d410068e@S-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>
Subject: Lorem Ipsum bum Lorem Ipsum has shared their name with you
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_5432106f1c926_12a33fec3247b7d41005c2";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_5432106f1c926_12a33fec3247b7d41005c2
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hi Scott,

Lorem Ipsum bum Lorem Ipsum sent you their name:

First Name: Lorem Ipsum bum


Kind Regards,
Lorem Ipsum bum Lorem Ipsum

----==_mimepart_5432106f1c926_12a33fec3247b7d41005c2
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Hi Scott,</p>

<p>Lorem Ipsum bum Lorem Ipsum sent you their name:</p>

<li><strong>First Name:</strong>Lorem Ipsum bum</li>

<p>Kind Regards,<br />
Lorem Ipsum bum Lorem Ipsum</p>

----==_mimepart_5432106f1c926_12a33fec3247b7d41005c2--

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/1
Completed 302 Found in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-06 14:45:51 +1100
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Profile Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles"  WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered profiles/_profile.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 97ms (Views: 95.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Profile Controller:

```
def email
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    destination = params[:to]
    name = params[:name]
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    user_mailer = UserMailer.profile(@profile, destination, name, user)
    if user_mailer.deliver
      flash[:success] = "Your name was emailed"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Your name could not be emailed"
      redirect_to @user
    end
  end
```

environments/production:

```
# Sendgrid config
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'example.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Incase this helps the folloing is some info related to user activation - to show how other emails are set up in the app (these emails work in real life when tested on heroku/gmail)

User Controller:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.profile = Profile.new
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

modles/user:

```
  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver
  end
```

Comment: I've reset heroku and tested it from scratch by hand - so I've created a new user, been sent an activation email to my gmail account :D. Then I've tried to send the second email and again it's notified me the email was sent but no email has appeared in my gmail :(

Comment: looks like it may have something to do with your config.default_url options, remove your host variable and just set it like this config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'smtp.sendgrid.net'}

Comment: hey, I tried that change and pushed it to heroku - still am not receiving the email to my gmail when i send an email from the profile page. the activate user email still sends (when a user signs up), but this change broke the activate link contained in that email which sends a user back to the site and activates their account. :(

Comment: ok well revert back to your original code then.. so you actually receive the sign up email in your inbox?

Comment: Hey, yup already did that part. The sign up email works again. Still no idea for the second email though - still says it's been emailed but I am not receiving it in my inbox. Thanks for the host suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

...So...turns out I wasn't sending it properly in my development environment after all! :s The email said it delivered, and 'delivered' in the terminal, but it wasn't passing the destination variable through as it should - so it had nowhere valid to send the email. (Terminal passed it 'destination' instead of 'example@example.com' and I hadn't check it properly). I fixed the view to pass the variable properly and voila!